# Postgres 9.3.5 not accepting VARCHAR(MAX) GORM

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails application that connects to a Postgres Plus Advanced Server. I have a domain in my Grails application that has a column of sqlType: VARCHAR(MAX). When the table is created by GORM, the column with the sqlType: VARCHAR(MAX) were created as Text. But when I changed my database to use PostgreSQL 9.3.5, it fails to create the table and says that it is encountering syntax error. Is that one of the difference between Postgres Plus Advanced Server and PostgreSQL 9.3.5? If so, how can I handle this so I won't have to change codes since there are a lot of domains that is using sqlType: VARCHAR(MAX) in my application.

Comment: really "MAX" or is that an actual number? why not use `text` in the first case and why not let gorm (`size:` iirc) take care of it for the later?  also please provide the original error if it has any additional value to the question.

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) looks like a SQL Server data type, that has been ported to  Postgres Plus Advanced Server. It's not a standard data type in PostgreSQL, that won't work. Just use VARCHAR or TEXT, that's the same anyway.

Comment: MAX is the value of the VARCHAR.

Below is the sample create script executed by GORM:

`create table Dummy (dummyId  bigserial not null, dummyName VARCHAR(MAX), primary key (dummyId ))`